# Mysql Syntax Error #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version

Tags: mysql, sql

PLease look at my query there is a syntax error:

```
SELECT min(t.`status`) ,
 t.`moddate`,case @rownum when 1 then
  @rowdate := @rowdate
  @rownum+1
  else
 @rowdate := ((@rowdate + INTERVAL @timediff SECOND) - INTERVAL @timediff SECOND) 
 end
FROM (SELECT `status`,`moddate` 
   FROM `globstats_graph`
   WHERE Cname='Cpmtree' AND IP='69.64.83.236'
   AND Port='3306' AND Variable='TABLE_LOCKS_IMMEDIATE'
   AND moddate between '2015-01-01 00:00' and '2015-02-01 00:00') t
,(
SELECT @rowdate :='2015-01-01 00:00',SELECT @timediff :=ROUND((TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,'2015-01-01 00:00','2015-02-01 00:00')/90)),@rownum:=1
) AS r, GROUP BY case @rownum when 1 then
  @rowdate := @rowdate
  @rownum+1
  else
 @rowdate := ((@rowdate + INTERVAL @timediff SECOND) - INTERVAL @timediff SECOND) 
 end
```

Could you please any one suggest me what went wrong.

Comment: what does that `THEN @rowdate := @rowdate @rownum + 1` mean?
This query looks like Oracle...

Comment: could you please suggest me how to do the same in mysql. @rowdate increment. then next time it will not satisfy first condition. is this wrong? if it is wrong please suggest me right syntax.

Comment: please explain what are you trying to achieve? your DB structure? sample data? expected results

Comment: hi. I want to find min of status for date range(timestamp). then i have to group the data that too exact  90 group i want. so i try to convert total second of date range then divide by 90. then i will get exact second than i try to add that with starting date as loop. when i group that 90 it will act as loop is it? so exactly it divide 90 group and it will give 90 record. could you suggest me how can i do that?

Comment: **CREATE TABLE `globstats_graph` (
 `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `IP` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
 `Cname` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
 `Port` int(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '3306',
 `Variable` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
 `status` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
 `moddate` datetime NOT NULL,
 `Servertime` datetime NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`ID`,`moddate`),
 KEY `idx_variable` (`Variable`),
 KEY `mod_index` (`moddate`),
 KEY `port_index` (`Port`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=67089835 DEFAULT CHARSET=ucs2** this is my table structure